# incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I had a sql statement that successfully ran on sql server but had an incorrect syntax problem when paste on vb.net. The incorrect syntax was near the keyword `'.'`, `'endfrom'` and `'group'`.

```
sql = "select distinct y.supplierID, y.Name," & _
             "StatusDesc=CASE when  y.status='N' then 'NEW' " & _
             "when y.status='B' then 'BLACKLISTED'" & _
             "when y.status='Q' then 'QUALIFIED'" & _
             "when y.status='R' then 'REJECTED' end , " & _
             "FlowStatusDesc = CASE when y.flowstatus='RC' then 'UNDER REVIEW'" & _
             "when y.flowstatus='PE' then 'POTENTIAL EXCLUSIVE'" & _
             "when y.flowstatus='PO' then 'POTENTIAL ORDINARY' ELSE '' end," & _
             "orderno=case when y.status='N' and y.flowstatus='' then '1'" & _
             "when y.status='N' and y.flowstatus<>'' then '2'   " & _
             "when y.status='R' and y.flowstatus='' then '3'" & _
             "when y.status='R' and y.flowstatus<>'' then '4'" & _
             "when y.status='Q' and y.flowstatus='' then '5'" & _
             "when y.status='Q' and y.flowstatus<>'' then '6'" & _
             "when y.status='B' and y.flowstatus=''  then '7' " & _
             "when y.status='B' and y.flowstatus<>'' then '8' else '9' end " & _
             "from (select x.supplierID, x.Name,x.Status,x.FlowStatus,x.AddWho" & _
             "from dbo.AP_Supplier x where x.AddWho IN (Select  distinct b.UserID from dbo.SC_UserRole a left join dbo.SC_UserRole b ON a.RoleID=b.RoleID where a.UserID=@User)" & _
             "group by x.supplierID,x.Name,x.Status,x.FlowStatus,x.AddWho)y " & _
             "group by y.supplierID,y.name,y.status, y.flowstatus" & _
             "order by orderno"
```

Comment: You have the correct answer, please check all of your query for missing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Insert spaces on the ends of all lines. E.g.

```
"group by y.supplierID,y.name,y.status, y.flowstatus" & _
"order by orderno"
```

results in the string

```
group by y.supplierID,y.name,y.status, y.flowstatusorder by orderno
```

which is a syntax error.

Comment: Print the generated sql string to a label, and see where it differs from the working one.

Comment: i have corrected all the missing spaces. there is only one incorrect syntax left and is near the word 'by'. i have tried editing, adding everything but still havent managed to correct the incorrect syntax error